# No such file or directory in a script

Tags: bash, file, permissions

I have some weird issue with a script. The line `exec $* ;;` which process `myfile` as an argument

```
if [ $# -gt 0 ]
then
   case $1 in
   -*) ;;
    *) exec $* ;;
   esac
fi
```

throws the error `myfile: No such file or directory`

For sure the file exists. I tried to sudo, I checked the perms, I set the owner as `root` but I keep on having this message.

Comment: Could be that `myfile` is a binary executable for 32 bits architecture while you are on a 64 bits machine. Try with `file myfile` and `uname -a`. Yes, I know, if this is right, the message is weird.

Comment: How do you run the script? I'm assuming you are passing just myfile? Is it in your path? Otherwise you need to specify the path. If it is in the same directory, use `./myfile`

Comment: It should be noted that it is *not* a good idea to `sudo` something that you do not fully understand, especially if it does not work as expected / at all.

Comment: @RenaudPacalet when I call `file myfile` I get `ELF 32-bit LSB executable, Intel 80386, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 2.6.18, BuildID[sha1]=0xc3ddbfd3a4e54b34d0cc0a22e56880dcdfdd719b, not stripped` and `uname -a` throws `Linux metamap-m 3.16.0-0.bpo.4-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 3.16.7-ckt11-1+deb8u3~bpo70+1 (2015-08-08) x86_64 GNU/Linux`/ How can I deal with that ? Because I am trying this code on a remote machine. The same code is running just fine with in my local `OSX`

Comment: @Newben: So, I was right, you are trying to run a 32 bits binary on a 64 bits machine. It runs fine with your local OSX because your local OSX is 32-bits or has the 32-bits libraries installed... Either install the 32-bits libraries on your 64 bits remote such that it can also run 32-bits binaries, or re-compile your application for the 64-bits target.

Comment: thank you so much @RenaudPacalet !

Answer (score 0):

Try with

```
exec "$@"
```

instead of

```
exec $*
```

to escape properly spaces in arguments.

### Example

```
bash -c "bash -c 'echo \$1' \$*" a b "c d" e f
```

incorrectly outputs `c`, and

```
bash -c "bash -c 'echo \$1' \"\$@\"" a b "c d" e f
```

correctly outputs `c d`.